# Why is the MappedSuperClass annotation no longer valid in combination with @Inheritance when migrating to Hibernate 5.4.x?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1, hibernate-5.x

I'm migrating several code bases to use Hibernate 5.4.x instead of Hibernate 5.2.x.

For an abstract base class I use

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractPersistentJPAObject extends AbstractPersistentObject {
    // some properties
}
```

However, the ORM complains about this with the error message

> An entity cannot be annotated with both `@Inheritance` and `@MappedSuperclass`

This was not a problem with Hibernate <= 5.2.x and now I wonder why this should not be allowed any more.

### Questions

1. Is this a bug or a feature? If a feature: What the *rationale* behind this change?
2. What can be done to circumvent the situation?
3. If "circumvent" is not a valid idea: How should the above code fragment be changed to migrate it towards Hibernate >= 5.4.x correctly.

Any solid answers welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answers are given below:

1. The mapping is **incorrect** according to the [JPA 2.2 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_2-mrel-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf), `@MappedSuperclass` and `@Inheritance` cannot be used together. It seems, the mapping above was **tolerated** in earlier Hibernate releases. However, this support seems to be removed in Hibernate 5.4.x.
2. To solve the issue in this specific scenario described above, you can replace `@MappedSuperclass` with `@Entity` and it should work fine.

There is also a similar question in the [Hibernate forum](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/can-no-longer-use-mappedsuperclass-and-inheritance-annotations-in-hibernate-5-4/2016/2).

You can also check [HHH-13217](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13217), in which Gail Badner & Vlad Mihalcea (both Hibernate Developers) are discussing about this issue.

In the next upcoming release 5.4.2, `@Inheritence` will be ignored, if it is used alongside `@MappedSuperclass` (see the related PR on [Github](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/2801)).